# Iterations around definite coordinates between two lists

Tags: python, iteration, coordinates

Classic battleships game.
I'm trying to make a space (looks like lower 'o') where we can't place another ship.

We have a 5*5 array of "O"s:

```
board = [['O','O','O','O','O'],['O','O','O','O','O'],['O','O','O','O','O'],
         ['O','O','O','O','O'],['O','O','O','O','O']]
```

I have placed a two cells ship and know it coordinates.

Coordinates are:

```
[(row, column),(row, column)]
[(0,0),(1,0)]

Board = [['S','O','O','O','O'],['S','O','O','O','O'],['O','O','O','O','O'],
         ['O','O','O','O','O'],['O','O','O','O','O']]
```

Now I have to find all 'O'-es around both coordinates and change it to 'o'. If there'll be 'S' don't change it.

```
def mark_nearby_cells(board):  # function for mar
    """
    function for marking cells nearby to currently placed ship 0 -> o
    """
    ships_coordinates = []
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        for j, ship in enumerate(row):
            if ship == "S":
                ship_coordinate = [row, column]
                ships_coordinates.append(ship_coordinate)

    for coordinate in ships_coordinates:
               #how to avoid simply iteration coordinate by adding and subtracting "1
            if ships_coordinates[ships_coordinates[0][0] - 1][ships_coordinates[0][1]] != 'S':
....
....
....

    return board
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there some code you're having trouble with? Please read about [ask], simply asking for free-code is off-topic here...

Comment: Please reformulate your question. Do you mean you're sent two coordinates in the format you sent, and you're asking how to change every `O` around them (the eight tiles around them? Only four? We have no way to know) ?

Comment: I'm newbie in programming and as stackoverflow user, so pardon me, please. From time to time it will be random coordinates. Now we have to change 4 "O".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an additional function to display the board and split your "mark_nearby_cells" function into two parts for simplicity.

```
import numpy as np

def print_board(board):
    """Displays the board nicely."""
    print("\n".join("".join(row) for row in board))
    print()

# Create the board.
X = 5
Y = 5
board = [['O' for _ in range(X)] for _ in range(Y)]
print_board(board)
# OOOOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO

# Place a ship.
for x, y in ((0, 0), (0, 1)):
    board[x][y] = "S"
print_board(board)
# SSOOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO

def detect_ships(board):
    """Returns a list of all the cells coordinates containing "S"."""
    ships_coordinates = []
    for x, row in enumerate(board):
        for y, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == "S":
                ships_coordinates.append((x, y))
    return ships_coordinates


def mark_nearby_cells(board):
    """Puts a lower "o" in the cells near a ship."""
    for (x, y) in ships_coordinates:
        for dx in (-1, +1):
            for dy in (-1, +1):
                xdx = np.clip(0, x+dx, X-1) # We don't want the coordinates to loop around the
                ydy = np.clip(0, y+dy, Y-1) # board so we trim them to [0; X] and [0; Y].
                cell = board[xdx][ydy]
                if cell == "O":
                    board[xdx][ydy] = "o"
    return board

ships_coordinates = detect_ships(board)
board = mark_nearby_cells(board)
print_board(board)
# SSoOO
# oooOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO
# OOOOO
```